# Make object assigned to class variable aware of parent

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to implement something similar to Django's model/manager pattern, but I can't figure out how Django makes the manager aware of the model it is managing.

For example, I want to implement something as follows:

```
class Manager:

    def create(self):
        # STUCK HERE
        return


class FooModel:
    field1 = None
    field2 = None

    objects = Manager()


class BarModel:
    field1 = None
    field2 = None

    objects = Manager()


foo = FooModel.objects.create(...)
bar = BarModel.objects.create(...)
```

The idea is that the `create()` method will perform some database operation and return an instance of the class with the `objects` variable. Similar to how Django works when you call `Model.objects.create()`. I've looked through the Django code on GitHub but I'm having difficulty finding how this is acheived.

How can I make the Manager instance aware of the object it is assigned to via the `objects` class variable?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make the class attribute be a **descriptor**:

```
class Manager:
  def __init__(self,cls): self.cls=cls
  # …
class PreManager:
  def __get__(self,cls,obj): return Manager(cls)

class Model:
  objects=PreManager()
```

Note that each access `Model.objects` will produce a **new** `Manager` object, so any persistent state should be stored on its `cls`.